# Developer Cloud Service and Packer Build Failing with HTTP 401 Unauthorized?

Tags: linux, packer, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oraclelinux

My Oracle Developer build failed and stated something about an HTTP unauthorized code:

```
 oracle-oci: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401
```

My packer json build has a bunch of elements I just setup and a bunch of them have `OCI` in the string...

```
  "builders": [
    {
      "user_ocid":"ocid1.user.oc1..",
      "tenancy_ocid": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..",
      "fingerprint":"0d:1e:...",
      "key_file":"oci_api_key.pem",
      "availability_domain": "uKbv:CA-TORONTO-1-AD-1",
      "region": "us-ashburn-1",
      "base_image_ocid": "ocid1.image.oc1.iad...",
      "compartment_ocid": "ocid1.compartment.oc1..",
      "image_name": "DevCS_MYSQL",
      "shape": "VM.Standard2.2",
      "ssh_username": "opc",
      "ssh_password": "welcome1",
      "subnet_ocid": "ocid1.subnet.oc1.ca-johnstown-1...",
      "type": "oracle-oci"
    }
  ],
```

How do I tell which one is wrong and causing the HTTP 401 unauthorized code?  I don't see any of the elements mentioned, and I don't see

```
[2019-08-21 12:44:50] Build scheduled. Build started by user helpdeskaleer@gmail.com
[2019-08-21 12:44:50] Build task id: 830601c8-5ba8-4dc4-8bdc-07abaff9de73
[2019-08-21 12:55:03] Build execution started.
[2019-08-21 12:55:03] Building on slave PackerTerraformNodeJS
[2019-08-21 12:55:02] Git: Checkout directory is the workspace root.
[2019-08-21 12:55:02] Git: git version 1.8.3.1
[2019-08-21 12:55:02] Git: Fetching from remote repository https://mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer.developer.ocp.oraclecloud.com/mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer/s/mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer_mysql-alphaoffice_10254/scm/MYSQL-PackerTerraform.git
[2019-08-21 12:55:02] /bin/git fetch --no-tags https://mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer.developer.ocp.oraclecloud.com/mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer/s/mysqlalphaoffice-helpdeskaleer_mysql-alphaoffice_10254/scm/MYSQL-PackerTerraform.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] Git: Checking out branch master
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] Git: Done
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] BEGIN shell script execution with /bin/sh -ex
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] + packer --version
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] 1.3.5
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] + tee output.txt
[2019-08-21 12:55:04] + packer build build.json
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32moracle-oci output will be in this color.[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32m==> oracle-oci: Creating temporary ssh key for instance...[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32m==> oracle-oci: Creating instance...[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;31m==> oracle-oci: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;31mBuild 'oracle-oci' errored: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] --> oracle-oci: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] + ls -l
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] total 56
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 2577 Aug 21 12:55 build.json
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 1406 Aug 21 12:55 compute.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  888 Aug 21 12:55 datasources.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder   99 Aug 21 12:55 Dockerfile
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  786 Aug 21 12:55 env-vars
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 2983 Aug 21 12:55 network.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 1675 Aug 21 12:55 oci_api_key.pem
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  450 Aug 21 12:55 oci_api_key_public.pem
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 1678 Aug 21 12:55 oci_instance_key
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  402 Aug 21 12:55 oci_instance_key.pub
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  488 Aug 21 12:55 outputs.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  874 Aug 21 12:55 output.txt
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder  260 Aug 21 12:55 provider.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] -rw-r-----. 1 builder builder 1726 Aug 21 12:55 variables.tf
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] + cat output.txt
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32moracle-oci output will be in this color.[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32m==> oracle-oci: Creating temporary ssh key for instance...[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;32m==> oracle-oci: Creating instance...[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;31m==> oracle-oci: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] [1;31mBuild 'oracle-oci' errored: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401[0m
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] ==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] --> oracle-oci: Problem creating instance: Service error:NotAuthenticated. The required information to complete authentication was not provided or was incorrect.. http status code: 401
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] ==> Builds finished but no artifacts were created.
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] /data/cibuild/830601c8-5ba8-4dc4-8bdc-07abaff9de73/tmp/script5780075887420937130.sh: line 5: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] Error: Command exited with status 2
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] END shell script execution
[2019-08-21 12:55:05] No artifacts requested
Slave log size 4.6 KB (4,622)
[2019-08-21 12:55:07]
[2019-08-21 12:55:07] Build completed.
[2019-08-21 12:55:07] Status: DONE Result: FAILED Duration: 5.0 sec
```

Answer (score 1):

401 NotAuthenticated indicates there's a problem with one of these values:

```
"user_ocid":"ocid1.user.oc1..",
"tenancy_ocid": "ocid1.tenancy.oc1..",
"fingerprint":"0d:1e:...",
"key_file":"oci_api_key.pem",
```

Those settings are all used to construct the signing string used to authenticate to OCI. When that authentication fails, you get a 401 NotAuthenticated response.

Comment: I bet it’s the .pem, that was by far the most confusing bit.  I’ve made public private key pairs before but I never changed their format.

Comment: Did you follow these instructions to create the key? https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm#How

Comment: I followed instructions in a video from an Oracle Workshop.  They said to run `ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f oci_api_key` add that into git via (**eyeroll**...copy and paste) and then generate the `oci_api_key.pem` file using `ssh-keygen -f oci_api_key -e -m PKCS8 > oci_api_key_pem.pub` and copy and paste that into the git repo.

Oh, also I'm on Windows 10 using git bash.

Comment: Please try the directions on https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm#How

Comment: Okay I tried the directions, and I verified the keys match (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/215767/how-do-i-verify-that-an-ssh-public-private-keypair-go-together-is-it-different/215769#215769) and then I copied them using `cat ./oci_api_key_public.pem | /c/windows/System32/clip` and `cat ./oci_api_key.pem | /c/windows/System32/clip` but my build still fails with the same error, must be something else...those ocid values don't change do they?  When you update the keys?

Comment: user / tenancy ocid values don't change based on keys, no. fingerprint does though. are you sure you added the public key in the OCI web portal? Also, does it work if you use one of the OCI SDKs, CLI, or Terraform module? Does your private key have a passphrase? I don't see a passphrase in your config above

Comment: No it doesn't have a passphrase and I bet I didn't update the finger print!